# telnet server c# with python telnetlib telnet

Tags: python, c#, networking, server, telnet

**telnet server c# with python telnetlib telnet**

> I want to create a telnet server using c#.
>
> But when I did some research I found ready-made c# code on githup It
> works very well and is what I'm looking for
>
> The problem I am facing. is that I created in python some code that
> logs into my c# server
>
> What I noticed is that when I manually login via putty.exe the server
> works very well but when I login via python telnetlib . python cannot
> type username and password to login to the server

telnet server c# with python telnetlib telnet clinet

I want to create a telnet server using c#.

But when I did some research I found ready-made c# code on githup It works very well and is what I'm looking for

The problem I am facing. is that I created in python some code that logs into my c# server

What I noticed is that when I manually login via putty.exe the server works very well but when I login via python telnetlib . python cannot type username and password to login to the server

python code

```
import getpass
import telnetlib

HOST = "192.168.253.1"
user = "root"
password = "r00t"

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)
tn.set_debuglevel(1)
tn.read_until(b"Username: ")
tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until(b"Password: ")
    tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")


print(tn.read_all().decode('ascii'))
```

> and this is debug of python code

```
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): IAC DO 1
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): IAC DO 33
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): IAC WILL 1
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): IAC WILL 3
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): recv b'Telnet Server\nUsername: '
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): send b'root\n'
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): recv b'r'
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): send b'r00t\n'
Telnet(192.168.253.1,23): recv b'r'
```

These are the codes of my c# server username is root . password is r00t

> Program.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace TelnetServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static Server s;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            s = new Server(IPAddress.Any);
            s.ClientConnected       += clientConnected;
            s.ClientDisconnected    += clientDisconnected;
            s.ConnectionBlocked     += connectionBlocked;
            s.MessageReceived       += messageReceived;
            s.start();

            Console.WriteLine("SERVER STARTED: " + DateTime.Now);

            char read = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar;

            do
            {
                if (read == 'b')
                {
                    s.sendMessageToAll(Console.ReadLine());
                }
            } while ((read = Console.ReadKey(true).KeyChar) != 'q');

            s.stop();
        }

        private static void clientConnected(Client c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("CONNECTED: " + c);

            s.sendMessageToClient(c, "Telnet Server" + Server.END_LINE + "Login: ");
        }

        private static void clientDisconnected(Client c)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("DISCONNECTED: " + c);
        }

        private static void connectionBlocked(IPEndPoint ep)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("BLOCKED: {0}:{1} at {2}", ep.Address, ep.Port, DateTime.Now));
        }

        private static void messageReceived(Client c, string message)
        {
            if (c.getCurrentStatus() != EClientStatus.LoggedIn)
            {
                handleLogin(c, message);
                return;
            }

            Console.WriteLine("MESSAGE: " + message);

            if (message == "kickmyass" || message == "logout" ||
                message == "exit")
            {
                s.kickClient(c);
                s.sendMessageToClient(c, Server.END_LINE + Server.CURSOR);
            }

            else if (message == "clear")
            {
                s.clearClientScreen(c);
                s.sendMessageToClient(c, Server.CURSOR);
            }

            else
                s.sendMessageToClient(c, Server.END_LINE + Server.CURSOR);
        }

        private static void handleLogin(Client c, string message)
        {
            EClientStatus status = c.getCurrentStatus();

            if (status == EClientStatus.Guest)
            {
                if (message == "root")
                {
                    s.sendMessageToClient(c, Server.END_LINE + "Password: ");
                    c.setStatus(EClientStatus.Authenticating);
                }

                else
                    s.kickClient(c);
            }

            else if (status == EClientStatus.Authenticating)
            {
                if (message == "r00t")
                {
                    s.clearClientScreen(c);
                    s.sendMessageToClient(c, "Successfully authenticated." + Server.END_LINE + Server.CURSOR);
                    c.setStatus(EClientStatus.LoggedIn);
                }

                else
                    s.kickClient(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> Client.cs

```
using System;
using System.Net;

namespace TelnetServer
{
    public enum EClientStatus
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The client has not been
        /// authenticated yet.
        /// </summary>
        Guest = 0,
        /// <summary>
        /// The client is authenticating.
        /// </summary>
        Authenticating = 1,
        /// <summary>
        /// The client is logged in.
        /// </summary>
        LoggedIn = 2
    }

    public class Client
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The client's identifier.
        /// </summary>
        private uint id;
        /// <summary>
        /// The client's remote address.
        /// </summary>
        private IPEndPoint remoteAddr;
        /// <summary>
        /// The connection datetime.
        /// </summary>
        private DateTime connectedAt;
        /// <summary>
        /// The client's current status.
        /// </summary>
        private EClientStatus status;
        /// <summary>
        /// The last received data from the client.
        /// </summary>
        private string receivedData;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Client"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">The client's identifier.</param>
        /// <param name="remoteAddress">The remote address.</param>
        public Client(uint clientId, IPEndPoint remoteAddress)
        {
            this.id = clientId;
            this.remoteAddr = remoteAddress;
            this.connectedAt = DateTime.Now;
            this.status = EClientStatus.Guest;
            this.receivedData = string.Empty;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the client identifier.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Client's identifier.</returns>
        public uint getClientID()
        {
            return id;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the remote address.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Client's remote address.</returns>
        public IPEndPoint getRemoteAddress()
        {
            return remoteAddr;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the connection time.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The connection time.</returns>
        public DateTime getConnectionTime()
        {
            return connectedAt;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the client's current status.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>The client's status.</returns>
        public EClientStatus getCurrentStatus()
        {
            return status;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the client's last received data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Client's last received data.</returns>
        public string getReceivedData()
        {
            return receivedData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the client's current status.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newStatus">The new status.</param>
        public void setStatus(EClientStatus newStatus)
        {
            this.status = newStatus;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sets the client's last received data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="newReceivedData">The new received data.</param>
        public void setReceivedData(string newReceivedData)
        {
            this.receivedData = newReceivedData;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Appends a string to the client's last
        /// received data.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="dataToAppend">The data to append.</param>
        public void appendReceivedData(string dataToAppend)
        {
            this.receivedData += dataToAppend;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Removes the last character from the
        /// client's last received data.
        /// </summary>
        public void removeLastCharacterReceived()
        {
            receivedData = receivedData.Substring(0, receivedData.Length - 1);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Resets the last received data.
        /// </summary>
        public void resetReceivedData()
        {
            receivedData = string.Empty;
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            string ip = string.Format("{0}:{1}", remoteAddr.Address.ToString(), remoteAddr.Port);

            string res = string.Format("Client #{0} (From: {1}, Status: {2}, Connection time: {3})", id, ip, status, connectedAt);

            return res;
        }
    }
}
```

> Server.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

namespace TelnetServer
{
    public class Server
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Telnet's default port.
        /// </summary>
        private const int PORT = 23;
        /// <summary>
        /// End of line constant.
        /// </summary>
        public const string END_LINE = "\r\n";
        public const string CURSOR = " > ";

        /// <summary>
        /// Server's main socket.
        /// </summary>
        private Socket serverSocket;
        /// <summary>
        /// The IP on which to listen.
        /// </summary>
        private IPAddress ip;
        /// <summary>
        /// The default data size for received data.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly int dataSize;
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the received data.
        /// </summary>
        private byte[] data;
        /// <summary>
        /// True for allowing incoming connections;
        /// false otherwise.
        /// </summary>
        private bool acceptIncomingConnections;
        /// <summary>
        /// Contains all connected clients indexed
        /// by their socket.
        /// </summary>
        private Dictionary<Socket, Client> clients;

        public delegate void ConnectionEventHandler(Client c);
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a client is connected.
        /// </summary>
        public event ConnectionEventHandler ClientConnected;
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a client is disconnected.
        /// </summary>
        public event ConnectionEventHandler ClientDisconnected;
        public delegate void ConnectionBlockedEventHandler(IPEndPoint endPoint);
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when an incoming connection is blocked.
        /// </summary>
        public event ConnectionBlockedEventHandler ConnectionBlocked;
        public delegate void MessageReceivedEventHandler(Client c, string message);
        /// <summary>
        /// Occurs when a message is received.
        /// </summary>
        public event MessageReceivedEventHandler MessageReceived;

        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="Server"/> class.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ip">The IP on which to listen to.</param>
        /// <param name="dataSize">Data size for received data.</param>
        public Server(IPAddress ip, int dataSize = 1024)
        {
            this.ip = ip;

            this.dataSize = dataSize;
            this.data = new byte[dataSize];

            this.clients = new Dictionary<Socket, Client>();

            this.acceptIncomingConnections = true;

            this.serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Starts the server.
        /// </summary>
        public void start()
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ip, PORT));
            serverSocket.Listen(0);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(handleIncomingConnection), serverSocket);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Stops the server.
        /// </summary>
        public void stop()
        {
            serverSocket.Close();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns whether incoming connections
        /// are allowed.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True is connections are allowed;
        /// false otherwise.</returns>
        public bool incomingConnectionsAllowed()
        {
            return acceptIncomingConnections;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Denies the incoming connections.
        /// </summary>
        public void denyIncomingConnections()
        {
            this.acceptIncomingConnections = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Allows the incoming connections.
        /// </summary>
        public void allowIncomingConnections()
        {
            this.acceptIncomingConnections = true;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Clears the screen for the specified
        /// client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c">The client on which
        /// to clear the screen.</param>
        public void clearClientScreen(Client c)
        {
            sendMessageToClient(c, "\u001B[1J\u001B[H");
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a text message to the specified
        /// client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="c">The client.</param>
        /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
        public void sendMessageToClient(Client c, string message)
        {
            Socket clientSocket = getSocketByClient(c);
            sendMessageToSocket(clientSocket, message);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a text message to the specified
        /// socket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">The socket.</param>
        /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
        private void sendMessageToSocket(Socket s, string message)
        {
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            sendBytesToSocket(s, data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends bytes to the specified socket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="s">The socket.</param>
        /// <param name="data">The bytes.</param>
        private void sendBytesToSocket(Socket s, byte[] data)
        {
            s.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(sendData), s);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends a message to all connected clients.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="message">The message.</param>
        public void sendMessageToAll(string message)
        {
            foreach (Socket s in clients.Keys)
            {
                try
                {
                    Client c = clients[s];

                    if (c.getCurrentStatus() == EClientStatus.LoggedIn)
                    {
                        sendMessageToSocket(s, END_LINE + message + END_LINE + CURSOR);
                        c.resetReceivedData();
                    }
                }

                catch
                {
                    clients.Remove(s);
                }
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the client by socket.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientSocket">The client's socket.</param>
        /// <returns>If the socket is found, the client instance
        /// is returned; otherwise null is returned.</returns>
        private Client getClientBySocket(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            Client c;

            if (!clients.TryGetValue(clientSocket, out c))
                c = null;

            return c;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the socket by client.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client">The client instance.</param>
        /// <returns>If the client is found, the socket is
        /// returned; otherwise null is returned.</returns>
        private Socket getSocketByClient(Client client)
        {
            Socket s;

            s = clients.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Value.getClientID() == client.getClientID()).Key;

            return s;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Kicks the specified client from the server.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="client">The client.</param>
        public void kickClient(Client client)
        {
            closeSocket(getSocketByClient(client));
            ClientDisconnected(client);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Closes the socket and removes the client from
        /// the clients list.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientSocket">The client socket.</param>
        private void closeSocket(Socket clientSocket)
        {
            clientSocket.Close();
            clients.Remove(clientSocket);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Handles an incoming connection.
        /// If incoming connections are allowed,
        /// the client is added to the clients list
        /// and triggers the client connected event.
        /// Else, the connection blocked event is
        /// triggered.
        /// </summary>
        private void handleIncomingConnection(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket oldSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;

                if (acceptIncomingConnections)
                {
                    Socket newSocket = oldSocket.EndAccept(result);

                    uint clientID = (uint)clients.Count + 1;
                    Client client = new Client(clientID, (IPEndPoint)newSocket.RemoteEndPoint);
                    clients.Add(newSocket, client);

                    sendBytesToSocket(
                        newSocket,
                        new byte[] {
                            0xff, 0xfd, 0x01,   // Do Echo
                            0xff, 0xfd, 0x21,   // Do Remote Flow Control
                            0xff, 0xfb, 0x01,   // Will Echo
                            0xff, 0xfb, 0x03    // Will Supress Go Ahead
                        }
                    );

                    client.resetReceivedData();

                    ClientConnected(client);

                    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(handleIncomingConnection), serverSocket);
                }

                else
                {
                    ConnectionBlocked((IPEndPoint)oldSocket.RemoteEndPoint);
                }
            }

            catch { }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Sends data to a socket.
        /// </summary>
        private void sendData(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;

                clientSocket.EndSend(result);

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, dataSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveData), clientSocket);
            }

            catch { }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Receives and processes data from a socket.
        /// It triggers the message received event in
        /// case the client pressed the return key.
        /// </summary>
        private void receiveData(IAsyncResult result)
        {
            try
            {
                Socket clientSocket = (Socket)result.AsyncState;
                Client client = getClientBySocket(clientSocket);

                int bytesReceived = clientSocket.EndReceive(result);

                if (bytesReceived == 0)
                {
                    closeSocket(clientSocket);
                    serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(handleIncomingConnection), serverSocket);
                }

                else if (data[0] < 0xF0)
                {
                    string receivedData = client.getReceivedData();

                    // 0x2E = '.', 0x0D = carriage return, 0x0A = new line
                    if ((data[0] == 0x2E && data[1] == 0x0D && receivedData.Length == 0) ||
                        (data[0] == 0x0D && data[1] == 0x0A))
                    {
                        //sendMessageToSocket(clientSocket, "\u001B[1J\u001B[H");
                        MessageReceived(client, client.getReceivedData());
                        client.resetReceivedData();
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        // 0x08 => backspace character
                        if (data[0] == 0x08)
                        {
                            if (receivedData.Length > 0)
                            {
                                client.removeLastCharacterReceived();
                                sendBytesToSocket(clientSocket, new byte[] { 0x08, 0x20, 0x08 });
                            }

                            else
                                clientSocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, dataSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveData), clientSocket);
                        }

                        // 0x7F => delete character
                        else if (data[0] == 0x7F)
                            clientSocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, dataSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveData), clientSocket);

                        else
                        {
                            client.appendReceivedData(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytesReceived));

                            // Echo back the received character
                            // if client is not writing any password
                            if (client.getCurrentStatus() != EClientStatus.Authenticating)
                                sendBytesToSocket(clientSocket, new byte[] { data[0] });

                            // Echo back asterisks if client is
                            // writing a password
                            else
                                sendMessageToSocket(clientSocket, "*");

                            clientSocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, dataSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveData), clientSocket);
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                    clientSocket.BeginReceive(data, 0, dataSize, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(receiveData), clientSocket);
            }

            catch { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate post of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72974828/telnet-server-c-sharp-receiving-strange-data

Comment: Does this answer your question? [telnet server c# with python telnetlib telnet clinet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72957887/telnet-server-c-sharp-with-python-telnetlib-telnet-clinet)